# Letterspacing memoir section headers

Tags: sectioning, memoir, soul, letterspacing

I'd like to add letterspacing to the `\section` commands with `\setsecheadstyle` in a `memoir` book.

I tried using `soul`:

```
\sodef\soSection{}{.1em}{.5em plus.1em}{.1em plus.1em minus.1em}
\setsecheadstyle{\sectionFont\MakeUppercase\soSection}
```

Of course this fails to compile because it should be `\soSection{...}`, but `memoir` inserts `\secheadstyle` this way:

```
\newcommand{\section}{%
  \sechook%
  \@startsection{section}{1}%  level 1
      {\secindent}%            heading indent
      {\beforesecskip}%        skip before the heading
      {\aftersecskip}%         skip after the heading
      {\normalfont\secheadstyle}} % font
```

It's possible to use a quick workaround, but it would be much neater to do this with styling.

```
\section[Suffering and Self-View]{\soSection{Suffering and Self-View}}
```

Can one set `\setsecheadstyle` with a `soul` command in it somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `memoir` class uses two optional arguments for the sectioning commands; the first optional argument is used for the ToC and the second one, for the running headers.

With the help of the `xparse` package you can define a new command behaving like the standard `\section` from `memoir`, but adding your `\soSection` command:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{xparse}

\sodef\soSection{}{.1em}{.5em plus.1em}{.1em plus.1em minus.1em}

\DeclareDocumentCommand\Section{oom}{
\IfNoValueTF{#1}
  {\section{#3}}
  {\IfNoValueTF{#2}{\section[#1]{#3}}{\section[#1][#2]{#3}}}
}

\begin{document}

\Section[Suffering and Self-View][Test]{Suffering and Self-View}

\end{document}
```

If you are never going to use the second optional argument for `\section`, a simpler solution can be given (with no new commands) using the `titlesec` package and its `explicit` option:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\sodef\soSection{}{.1em}{.5em plus.1em}{.1em plus.1em minus.1em}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{\soSection{#1}}

\begin{document}

\section[Suffering and Self-View]{Suffering and Self-View}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I went for an `xparse` definition. `titlesec` was rewriting too much of the already defined `memoir` styles.