# Soul letterspacing in memoir sections with \setsecheadstyle

Tags: sectioning, memoir, soul, letterspacing

I realize I have asked almost the same [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40377/letterspacing-memoir-section-headers) earlier.

There, the answer involved `xparse` or `titlesec`. Titlesec however gets into conflicts with memoir's pagestyles (running header settings, `\leftmark` and so on), and a new command `\Section` with xparse bypasses the useful mechanisms of memoir for the default `\section`.

I tend to think it shouldn't be too difficult use `memoir`'s `\setsecheadstyle`, but somehow I'm not getting the command definition right.

So I'm trying to add `soul` letterspacing to the `\section` formatting in a
`memoir` document. The docs recommend `\setsecheadstyle`.

```
\newcommand\sectionFmt[1]{%
  \MakeUppercase{\soSection{#1}}%
}
\setsecheadstyle{\sectionFmt}
```

It errors out with `! A <box> was supposed to be here.` However,
`\textit{#1}` works fine.

It seems I'm just not passing the argument properly. How to do this right?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\makeatletter

\usepackage{soul}
\sodef\soSection{}{.1em}{.5em plus.1em}{.1em plus.1em minus.1em}

\newcommand\sectionFmt[1]{%
  % This errors out with: '! A <box> was supposed to be here.'
  \MakeUppercase{\soSection{#1}}%
  % But \textit{} works.
  %\MakeUppercase{\textit{#1}}%
}

\setsecheadstyle{\sectionFmt}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

And most conclusive of all, there are the two hideous results which the doctor
obtained from a certain pair of formulae during his final investigations.

\section{Monstrous Implications}

Results which virtually proved the authenticity of the papers and of their
monstrous implications at the same time that those papers were borne forever
from human knowledge.

-- The Case of Charles Dexter Ward, H.P. Lovecraft

\end{document}
```

Comment: The main problem is that the head style is not just fed the actual text, it also get a lot of formatting as well, and `soul` does not handle that very well. Try just letting `\sectionFmt` return the input unaltered plus type it to the log via `\typeout{#1}`, then you will see the difference. Perhaps `microtype` might help better (untested).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works using `microtype` instead, you may need to fine tune it a bit, see the `microtype` manual (it might be a bit hard to understand, I did not)

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\newcommand\sectionFmt[1]{%
  \bfseries\lsstyle\MakeUppercase{#1}%
}
\setsecheadstyle{\sectionFmt}
```