# Spacing capitals in section headings

Tags: sectioning, titlesec, microtype

I'm using `titlesec` to customise my section headings.
I want to have my subsections in capitals, which I can achieve with the `\uppercase` function, but all typographic style guides suggest that caps should have increased space.

The `microtype` package can apply increased letter spacing, according to:
[Enlarging tracking (= letter spacing)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62346/enlarging-tracking-letter-spacing/62351#62351)

The thread mentions a command of `\textls` which I have tried inserting into the titlesec options, but TexShop throws up an error when typesetting.

Alternatively, using the switch `\lsstyle` doesn't work either.

Here's MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[letterspace=150]{microtype}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\large}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{2.5ex}{2.5ex}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\small\uppercase\lsstyle}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{2.5ex}{0ex}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\sffamily\itshape}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{1.5ex}{0ex}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]{\normalfont\normalsize}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subparagraph}[runin]{\normalfont\normalsize}{\thesubparagraph}{1em}{}

\title{Minimal Working Example}
\date{}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Section 1}
Content

\subsection{Subsection, my friend}

\end{document}
```

Edit: am using XeLaTeX in my non-MWE to access system fonts. The error I get (see comment to an answer below) occurs in XeLaTeX.

Answer (score 5):

You should be using `\MakeUppercase`, not `\uppercase`, although they're almost equivalent in a XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX context.

The `letterspacing` for `microtype` option cannot be used with XeLaTeX, but it can be replaced by `\addfontfeatures{LetterSpace=...}`.

So, here is a working example; one *might* redefine `\lsstyle` when XeLaTeX is used, but I believe it's better not to and use a personal command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifluatex}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}

\ifluatex
  \microtypesetup{letterspace=150}
  \newcommand{\myletterspacing}{\lsstyle}
\else
  \newcommand{\myletterspacing}{\addfontfeatures{LetterSpace=20}}
\fi

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\large}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{2.5ex}{2.5ex}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\small\myletterspacing\MakeUppercase}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{2.5ex}{0ex}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\sffamily\itshape}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{1.5ex}{0ex}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]{\normalfont\normalsize}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subparagraph}[runin]{\normalfont\normalsize}{\thesubparagraph}{1em}{}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Minimal Working Example}
\date{}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Section 1}
Content

\subsection{Subsection, my friend}

\lipsum[1]

\myletterspacing
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can make this work just fine on my MWE, but going to my non-MWE I get compile error on the first instance of `\subsection` - where `\myletterspacing` occurs. I have tried copying and pasting your `\titlesec` commands to make sure I have it right, but it's not going. Must be clashing with some other command/package I have.

Answer (score 4):

You need to place the `\lsstyle` before the `\uppercase` command, not after.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[letterspace=150]{microtype}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\large}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{2.5ex}{2.5ex}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\small\lsstyle\uppercase}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{2.5ex}{0ex}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\sffamily\itshape}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{1.5ex}{0ex}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]{\normalfont\normalsize}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subparagraph}[runin]{\normalfont\normalsize}{\thesubparagraph}{1em}{}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Minimal Working Example}
\date{}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Section 1}
Content

\subsection{Subsection, my friend}

\lipsum[1]

\lsstyle
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

*Update*
This particular feature of `microtype` does not work with XeLaTeX.  But there you can use the font features via `fontspec`.  In particular `\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=15}` seems to be the sort of thing you are after:

[image: xelatex sample]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\large}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{2.5ex}{2.5ex}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\small\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=15}\uppercase}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{2.5ex}{0ex}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\sffamily\itshape}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{1.5ex}{0ex}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]{\normalfont\normalsize}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subparagraph}[runin]{\normalfont\normalsize}{\thesubparagraph}{1em}{}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Minimal Working Example}
\date{}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Section 1}
Content

\subsection{Subsection, my friend}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I get the following response in the console when hitting H for help: Run pdftex or luatex, or run 'soul' package instead. But I'm typesetting under pdftex

Comment: The above compiles fine under `pdflatex` for me.  What error message are you getting?

Comment: As I said above: "Run pdftex or luatex, or use the `soul' package instead."

Comment: Which suggests you have not run `pdflatex`...

Comment: Ah yes. While it does compile under `pdflatex`, see my edit to original post and my own answer below - I'm using XeLaTeX for font control which clashes various attempts to get letterspaced, capitalised section headings. I have given up now, it's far more effort than it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
\titleformat{\subsection}{\small\lsstyle\uppercase}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
```

it changes the order of `\lsstyle` and `\uppercase`

Comment: I get the following response in the console when hitting H for help: Run pdftex or luatex, or run 'soul' package instead. But I'm typesetting under pdftex.

Answer (score 0):

It appears my issue is/was with XeLaTex.

Gonzalo Medina provides an answer to this similar question: [Letterspacing memoir section headers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40377/letterspacing-memoir-section-headers)

In his second MWE he provides an example of using the `soul` package with `titlesec`.

In the MWE below I have applied spacing to section headings in a similar manner.

In addition to calling and defining the `soul` package, note the use of `[explicit]` prior to `titlesec`and invoking `soul` at the end of each format line.

Again, this is for XeLaTex typesetting with `fontspec` defining fonts.

According to the `soul` documentation: http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/soul/soul.pdf
the parameters are as follows:

\sodef⟨cmd⟩{⟨font⟩}{⟨inter-letter space⟩}{⟨inner space⟩}{⟨outer space⟩}

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode,setspace}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Arno Pro}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text]{Century Gothic}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Inconsolata}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{soul}
\sodef\soSection{}{.1em}{.5em plus.1em}{.1em plus.1em minus.1em}
\sodef\soSubsection{}{.1em}{.5em plus.1em}{.1em plus.1em minus.1em}
\sodef\soSubsubsection{}{.1em}{.5em plus.1em}{.1em plus.1em minus.1em}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\large}{\thesection}{1em}{\soSection{#1}}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{2.5ex}{2.5ex}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\small\uppercase}{\thesubsection}{1em}{\soSubsection{#1}}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{2.5ex}{0ex}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\sffamily\itshape}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{\soSubsubsection{#1}}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{1.5ex}{0ex}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]{\normalfont\normalsize}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subparagraph}[runin]{\normalfont\normalsize}{\thesubparagraph}{1em}{}

\title{Minimal Working Example}
\date{}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Section 1}
\lipsum[1]

\subsection{Subsection, my friend}
\lipsum[2]

\subsubsection{Subsubsub}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Too good to be true. This answer (possibly the `soul` package) is incompatible with `\tableofcontents`.