# single command to achieve spaced font

Tags: fonts

I really like the spaced font that's done for the headings in

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/184327/109804

Is there a single command I can use to achieve the same effect for fragments of writing? I just want to write

```
\specialfont{fancy spaced writing here}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please tell us which tex engine and format -- pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, something else? -- you use. Please also clarify what you mean by "spaced font". E.g., do you mean letter-spacing? Should the `\specialfont` macro use the same font face (albeit letter-spaced) as is in use in the surrounding text, or should a different font face be used? If so, which one?

Comment: I don't know if spacing is considered different than font. All I'm saying is that I want the text I have written in my command to look the way "subsection, my friend" looks in the link. It would be great to be able to make the font different from the surrounding text (the font itself is not so important, but I would like to know how to be able to change it). I don't know what engine I have. How do I find out?

Comment: What does the first line of the `.log` file say? E.g., does it start with "This is pdfTeX, Version ..."?

Comment: yes pdfTeX version 3.14

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're using pdfLaTeX, you could load either the `microtype` or the `letterspace` package and employ the `\textls*` macro.

The amount of letterspacing (also known as "tracking") may be set via the optional argument of `\textls*`. In the example below, I've chosen a value of `100`; feel free to change this setting as you see fit.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{letterspace} % or: \usepackage{microtype}
\newcommand\specialfont[1]{\textls*[100]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\specialfont{fancy letterspaced writing here}

FANCY LETTERSPACED WRITING HERE
\end{document}
```

Comment: :-) ............