# Format the chapter name to have letterspacing

Tags: memoir, chapters, titlesec, microtype, letterspacing

I'm using the `memoir` class, and the `microtype` and  `titlesec` packages. I have the chapter names appearing in smallcaps, and I would like the spacing between the letters increased a little bit. Here's the minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[smalldemyvopaper,11pt,twoside,onecolumn,openright,extrafontsizes]{memoir}
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype} % for micro-typographical adjustments
\usepackage{titlesec} % for manipulation of chapter titles

\SetTracking{encoding=*,shape=sc}{120}
\newcommand*{\textsomels}[1]{\textls[25]{#1}}

% chapter title manipulation
% padding with zero
\renewcommand*\thechapter{\ifnum\value{chapter}<10 0\fi\arabic{chapter}}
% chapter title display
\titleformat
{\chapter}
[display]
{\normalfont\scshape\huge}
{\HUGE\thechapter\centering}
{0pt}
{\vspace{18pt}\centering}[\vspace{42pt}]
% BEGIN THE DOCUMENT
\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{\textsomels{Chapter One}}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

I get the right output with `\chapter{\textsomels{Chapter One}}`, but when I make the line, `{\normalfont\scshape\huge}`, which is the one that is responsible for the chapter title to `{\textsomels\normalfont\scshape\huge}`, the formatting messes up.

I do not want to write `\chapter{\textsomels{Chapter Name}}` every time.

Where am I making the mistake? I'm new to TeX.

Comment: Could you provide a minimum working example that compiles and demonstrates the issue, to help save some work for those who would otherwise offer to help you?

Comment: Apologies. I'll edit the question with the `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`, and add some text. The rest of the preamble is there in the question.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40377/letterspacing-memoir-section-headers

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184301/spacing-capitals-in-section-headings would indicate that using `\lsstyle` instead of `\textls{#1}` would work.

Comment: `lsstyle` does change the spacing, but may I know how to control the spacing? I'm sorry if it is a dumb question.
`\newcommand*{\textsomels}[1]{\lsstyle[20]}` doesn't seem to control it. I'm sure I've gotten the syntax wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the OP notes in the comment, `\lsstyle`, while it works as an argument to `titlesec`, does not allow for the letterspacing value to be explicitly set.

Here, I introduce `\lsstylehelp{}` in lieu of `\lsstyle`, where the argument is the letterspacing value to set for the subsequent `\lsstyle`.   The definition is simply `\newcommand\lsstylehelp[1]{\edef\MT@letterspace@{#1}\lsstyle}`

Here is the MWE.

```
\documentclass[smalldemyvopaper,11pt,twoside,onecolumn,openright,extrafontsizes]{memoir}
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype} % for micro-typographical adjustments
\usepackage{titlesec,lipsum} % for manipulation of chapter titles

\SetTracking{encoding=*,shape=sc}{120}
\newcommand*{\textsomels}[1]{\textls[305]{#1}}

% chapter title manipulation
% padding with zero
\renewcommand*\thechapter{\ifnum\value{chapter}<10 0\fi\arabic{chapter}}
% chapter title display
\titleformat
{\chapter}
[display]
{\normalfont\scshape\huge\lsstylehelp{300}}
{\HUGE\thechapter\centering}
{0pt}
{\vspace{18pt}\centering}[\vspace{42pt}]

\makeatletter
\newcommand\lsstylehelp[1]{\edef\MT@letterspace@{#1}\lsstyle}
\makeatother
% BEGIN THE DOCUMENT
\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Chapter One}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{\textsomels{Chapter One}}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: PERFECT! That worked, thank you!
I've marked this as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace `\titleformat` with this:

```
\titleformat
{\chapter}
[display]
{\filcenter\normalfont\scshape\huge}
{\HUGE\thechapter}
{18pt}
{\textsomels}[\vspace{42pt}]
```

[image]

Comment: That worked, too! Thank you!
Both the solutions worked; can I not select both of them as answers?

Comment: No, but it's unimportant. Note I simplified the rest of the code inside \titleformat.